# How to avoid mixed/insecure content warnings when having deep links to non-http schemes for mobile apps?

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, https

Let's say I have a mobile app that listens to all "myawesomeapp" scheme links so it can open them in the app and I have a related website. Now when a page, for eg, `https://myawesomeapp.com/home/` is loaded in the browser, I create an iframe dynamically and add it to the document with the src of `myawesomeapp://myawesomeapp.com/home/` so that my app can try and open up that page within itself. But most modern browsers will display an insecure/mixed content warning when such a link is created from a page served over HTTPS. Is there a way around this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried using window.open instead of an iframe?

Comment: Given that you are not _really_ creating a custom protocol, but rather just opening the page within a browser in `myawesomeapp`, I would suggest not using the `myawesomeapp://` scheme at all. In your Android and iOS apps, register url handlers for `http` and `https` filtered on on `myawesomeapp.com`.

Comment: @BenGrimm Any idea how to fix this for custom protocol?

Answer (score 2):

Browser can't guarantee that the protocol `myawesomeapp` is secure (like https). So as a security consideration, it MUST warn the user that insecure content is being loaded in an otherwise secure page.

You can create a service on server to redirect to another scheme. i.e. `https://website.com/deeplink/appscheme/path` will redirect browser to `appscheme://path`.

Comment: I tried this (have a redirection endpoint), but this isn't triggering the intent.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) the `iframe src` trick doesn't work anymore.

If you want your app to automatically trigger upon landing on a web page, I found putting this that web page's `<head>` tag works:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=myprotocol:/path1" />`

Where `myprotocol` is the "scheme" in your intent filter.

However, I am not sure if this method will also be "blocked" future versions of the browser. As the link above stated:

> you should implement a **user gesture** to launch the app via a custom scheme, or use the “intent:” syntax

It seems to me they want intents to be triggered only by user-initiated gestures such as clicking a button, or a link. There could be security issues if a webpage can trigger intents on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is if the user clicks a link to your site, he gets the option to open the link in your app instead of in the browser.

The way to do this in Android is registering an intent filter so your app gets launched when the user clicks a link to your domain name.

See the example intent filter here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Browser

This is better than using a custom scheme because the link will lead the user straight to the app, instead of loading the site in a browser which will then open the app.

This works different than in iOS, yes. To keep both compatible, you could sniff the useragent and show the iframe with the custom scheme only in iOS browsers.

Comment: Sorry, what I'm after is a solution that works for both iOS and Android. Also, user agent sniffing is something I'd avoid on the mobile site (because like many other mobile sites), this too is a single page app. So I'd rather not add any overhead to response times when currently I'm just serving a static page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code out? Call it when the document is ready and pass to it the url of your app.

```
var redirect = function ( location ) 
{
    var iframe = $('<iframe></iframe>').attr( 'src', location ).css({
        width: 1,
        height: 1
    });
    $( 'body' ).append( iframe );
    iframe.remove();
    iframe = null;
};
```